# Show Entity Reference items as table

Tags: nodes, entities

I have two Content Types (Country, City).
I want to display full contents of City in Country, so I did like this:
- create a field in World Content type 
- set this field as entity reference (City).

Drupal print the two City contents in World successfully but I want put the city content in horizontal tabs.

I tried the module [references_tabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/references_tabs), but it can put only one field reference at time.

How can I do so?

Thanks

Comment: [Quick tabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs) Module would do that. in conjunction with [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)

Comment: Nice try, but quick tabs cannot be added as field in the content type. Is there any other way to render a referenced entity in a content type? The hard code mod is the last solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the description of  the   [References Tabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/references_tabs) module

> This module allows to render nodes referenced via a node reference
>   field in tabs, with node titles as tab titles and rendered nodes as
>   tab content.

it is only support **Nod referenced** not **entity reference** ,you can see [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1708584)  that it is not support `entity reference` , you can change your field from entity reference to node reference type.

Comment: This module cut the City fields individually to let you display single field in World. I want to tab nodes 'City', not fields of City...

Comment: @GaelSapori please look at the setting carefully, I think it can show all of them

Comment: I want to tab City nodes in World, not City fields in World...

Comment: @GaelSapori I update my answer with more details.

Comment: Referenced tabs does not let me use check box for multiple nodes (and of course tabs). Only radio buttons

Comment: Thank you zhilevan I was able to do that with node referenced.

Comment: @GaelSapori you're welcome ;)